# Remove responsive from the wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I have used the _tk theme for my theme. Link to the theme `https://github.com/Themekraft/_tk` . Now i want to remove the responsive feature from theme. How can i remove the responsive feature from the theme ? Is there any function to desable the responsive. If you have used the theme, please help me to remove the responsive feature.

Comment: https://github.com/Themekraft/_tk/blob/master/style.css  comment on @import url( includes/css/bootstrap-wp.css );

Comment: Whoever downvoted the two answers below, kindly comment why these were voted so.

Comment: Hey i think, you did not look to the _tk theme and give the answer. I used the _tk theme as i told previously. So please give the valuable comments on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i asked the question that how can i remove the responsive from the theme. I got that _tk theme used the bootstrap 3.0 and the latest 3.0 bootstrap can be deactivated the responsive by do the bellow.

```
    Omit the viewport <meta> mentioned in the CSS docs
    Override the width on the .container for each grid tier with a single width, for example width: 970px !important; Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
    If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
    For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.

You'll still need Respond.js for IE8 (since our media queries are still there and need to be processed). This disables the "mobile site" aspects of Bootstrap.
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the media queries either in the css or head

Look for either (similar to)

**Head**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px)'>
```

or

**CSS**

```
@media screen {
      /* whatever */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using bootstrap. remove media queries from your bootstrap css and below is path

```
includes/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
```

and below line from header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```